# Never push to a certain remote

Tags: git, git-remote

I have push access to a Git repository, but in practice I never want to push directly to that repository.

Example: I although I have push access to a Github repository, I almost always want to instead push to my fork of that repository, then submit a pull request, so that we can use the Github code review process.

How can I add that remote so that I can pull from it, but prevent myself from accidentally pushing to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best I've come up with is this: note that each remote has (at least) two URLs; one for pushing and one for fetching.

If you set the push URL of a remote to the empty string, you will get an error whenever you try to push to it:

```
git remote set-url  --push  origin ""
```

Now,

```
$ git push origin master
fatal: No path specified. See 'man git-pull' for valid url syntax
```

It's not the most obvious error message, though.